# Managing Lerna monorepo with packages using both Vue 2 and Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3, lerna

I'm trying to create PR to contribute to opensource library which uses Lerna to manage multiple packages and npm as package manager.

The library already supports Vue 2 using package `support-vue`. The purpose of my PR is to add Vue 3 support by creating new package called `support-vue3`.

Package `support-vue` depends on Vue 2 and Vue 2 compatible versions of certaing packages (`vue-router`, `@vue/test-utils`), while package `support-vue3` depends on Vue3 compatible versions of these packages.

The problem I can't solve is how to use different versions of Vue and related packages in `support-vue` and in `support-vue3`. AFAIK Lerna hoists only one version to root `node_modules` (Vue 2 in this case). I can only get one package to work at a time depending on which version of Vue is installed.

I need to have different version of Vue installed for each package.

I tried going around it by using package aliases in `package.json` like so:

```json
{
 "devDependencies": {
   "vue2": "npm:vue@2",
   "vue3": "npm:vue@3",
   "@vue/test-utils1": "npm:@vue/test-utils@1",
   "@vue/test-utils2": "npm:@vue/test-utils@2",
   ...
 }
}
```

and importing Vue from these, but then `vue` dependency can't be found in `@vue/test-utils` and other packages requiring Vue as peer dependency.

I also tried adding filters to `lerna.json` to disable hoisting of vue to root `package.json` and adding vue only to dependencies of the support packages but to no avail.

Is it possible to use different version of Vue in each package with Lerna or is this a dead end?

Comment: How did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Lerna supports such thing you can use SingleSpa or OpenComponent instead